# creating a function to find a square root of a number using the following method

Tags: python, square-root

Recently, I was trying to create an algorithm for finding a square root of a number. I am kind of new to python programming. This is my implementation:

```
def findSquareRt(num):
    n = 8         #Initial Guess
    while True:
        if n**2 < num:
            if not num/n == n:
                temp = n
                n = num/n
                if (int((temp+n)/2))**2 == num:
                    return ((temp+n)/2)
                else:
                    n = (temp+n)/2
```

---

But when i run the above code it just doesn't produce any output. Maybe it is the looping condition which is causing this, but i cant figure that out.

Comment: From the first look, your `if` block may never be true, thus never returning anything. It's going in an infinite loop because it doesn't have a `return` or `break` to get to.

Comment: Secondly your actual termination condition, which results in a `return` is using `==`, which may also never be true.

Comment: Thanks @quamarana, I guess the the integer conversion will never allow initial guesses to return a square root because it neglects the trailing decimal points. Now i am trying to think of a different way for this completing this condition.

Comment: @user15294091 thanks for responding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for responding to the question, From responses there were two problems:

### first problem:

```
if n**2 < num:
```

this condition is always returning False on second or some other future iterations, and is redundant so this should be removed in order to get a solution.

### second problem:

```
if (int((temp+n)/2))**2 == num:
```

The integer conversion of the expression ((temp+n)/2) is returning floor value of the float numbers, which effects the precision of the output hence the program stuck infinitely in the loop waiting for the condition to be True. Hence needed to be changed.

### Final Solution:

```
def findSquareRt(num):
    n = 8               #Initial Guess
    while True:
        if not num/n == n:
            temp = n
            n = num/n
            if (((temp+n)/2))**2 == num:
                return ((temp+n)/2)
            else:
                n = (temp+n)/2
        else:
            return n
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of issues, one of them being that you will get an infinite loop if `n**2 > num`.
A simpler way of doing this would be something like this:

```
def findSquareRt(num):
     return num**0.5
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out that conditional mistake, but i am actually trying to solve it using a set of instruction given above.